# map() to create a new column inside each list item

Tags: r, tidyverse, purrr, lm

I have a list of `lm()` model outputs, for example (reproducible example below):

```
library(tidyverse)
mtcars
model1 <- lm(mpg ~ disp, data = mtcars)
model2 <- lm(mpg ~ disp + hp, data = mtcars)
models <- list(model1, model2)
models
```

Which gives a list that looks like this:

```
[[1]]

Call:
lm(formula = mpg ~ disp, data = mtcars)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)         disp  
   29.59985     -0.04122  


[[2]]

Call:
lm(formula = mpg ~ disp + hp, data = mtcars)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)         disp           hp  
   30.73590     -0.03035     -0.02484
```

I'm able to use `map()` to run a function (eg `AIC()`) on all of the models in the list, eg:

```
map(.x = models, .f = AIC)
```

which returns values for each model:

```
[[1]]
[1] 170.2094

[[2]]
[1] 168.6186
```

How can I take the output above (i.e. the outputs of the AIC() function) and use it to create a new column inside each list item (i.e. create a new column of AIC() output for each model)?

Essentially, I'm trying to perform the code below, but using `map()`:

```
model1$AIC <- AIC(model1)
model2$AIC <- AIC(model2)
```

First preference would be a tidyverse `map()` solution, but I'll be happy with any other solutions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `map`

```
new_model <- purrr::map(models, ~{.x$AIC = AIC(.x);.x})

new_model[[1]]$AIC
#[1] 170.2094

new_model[[2]]$AIC
#[1] 168.6186
```

Similarly, we can also use `lapply`

```
new_model <- lapply(models, function(x) {x$AIC = AIC(x);x})
```

Comment: For anyone reading this in the future trying to solve similar questions, I thoroughly recommend reading through @ronak-shah's answer feed as a great way to learn more about R.

Comment: with the final part `;.x})`--I'm not familiar with using a semicolon in an anonymous function in `map()` is there a search term I should look for to look up documentation?

Comment: @JeremyK. it's a way to write multiple statements in a single line.

Answer (score 1):

We can just apply the `AIC` directly

```
library(purrr)
map_dbl(models, AIC)
#[1] 170.2094 168.6186
```

If we need to update the 'models'

```
for(i in seq_along(models)) models[[i]][['AIC']] <- AIC(models[[i]])
```

Comment: Thank you. How do I then create a new column in models, that contains the AIC?

Comment: @JeremyK.  There is no column (as it is not a data.frame object)